# Loop through all elements except the last one using range-based for loop

Tags: c++, loops

For starters, a short snippet of what I want to achieve:

```
std::vector<std::string> v{ "one", "two", "three", "four" };
for (const std::string& str : drop_last(v)) {
   cout << str << ' ';
}
```

The code above should print: "one two three ".

In order to make this possible, I implemented the following structure:

```
template <typename Container>
struct drop_last {
   using const_iterator = typename Container::const_iterator;

   explicit drop_last(const Container& container_) : m_container(container_) {}

   const_iterator begin() {
      return m_container.begin();
   }

   const_iterator end() {
      return m_container.empty() ? m_container.end() : std::prev(m_container.end());
   }
private:
   const Container& m_container;
};
```

This code works fine except when working with temporary objects (In this case, assert "cannot dereference value-initialised map/set iterator" occurs ):

```
std::vector<int> return_temporary_vector() {
   vector<int> v;
   // ...
   return v;
}

int main(int argc_, char* argv_[]) {
   for (int value : drop_last(return_temporary_vector())) {
      // ...
   }
   // ...
}
```

How can I adapt the structure of `drop_last` so that the following conditions are met:

- correct work with temporary objects
- avoid unnecessary copying when possible. That is, simply replacing `const Container& m_container;` with `Container m_container;` is not suitable.

Comment: "a fall occurs"? Can you be more specific?

Comment: @TonyK Reproduced in MVS15. Instead, the vector used set. assert "cannot dereference value-initialised map/set iterator".

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thank you for noticing. Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a template function with forwarding reference, you can use that to pass either `Container` or `Container&` forward to your class.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename Container>
struct drop_last_impl {
   using const_iterator = typename std::remove_reference_t<Container>::const_iterator;

   explicit drop_last_impl(Container&& container_) : m_container(std::forward<Container>(container_)) {}

   const_iterator begin() {
      return m_container.begin();
   }

   const_iterator end() {
      return m_container.empty() ? m_container.end() : std::prev(m_container.end());
   }
private:
   const Container m_container;
};

template <typename Container>
auto drop_last(Container&& container) {
    return drop_last_impl<Container>(std::forward<Container>(container));
}

std::vector<int> return_temporary_vector() {
   std::vector<int> v{1,2,3};
   // ...
   return v;
}

int main() {
   for (int value : drop_last(return_temporary_vector())) {
      std::cout << value << std::endl;
   }
   std::vector<int> v{1,2,3};
    for (int value : drop_last(v)) {
      std::cout << value << std::endl;
   }
   // ...
}
```

`drop_last_impl` now moves into a `std::vector<int>` if passed an rvalue, or initializes a `std::vector<int>&` if passed an lvalue.
`std::remove_reference_t` is needed since if instatiated with `std::vector<int>&` we would not find `const_iterator`.